# to become, becoming

Tags: grammar, infinitive-vs-gerund

My dream was to become a scientist. 
My dream was becoming a scientist.

Which one is correct? or Do you have any idea to make it sound natural?

Comment: Even though *My dream was becoming a scientist* sounds strange, *Becoming a scientist was my dream* sounds okay. *My dream was becoming true/a reality/etc.* is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence links the action of "becoming" with its subject, **My dream**. By this, your dream was in the process of turning into a scientist. Dreams cannot do that.

The first sentence is commonly phrased and would be acceptable.